# How do I use Visualforce to generate a CSV file that can be downloaded using IE8?

Tags: visualforce, csv, data-export, internet-explorer

I am using the following Visualforce Page as an endpoint that generates a CSV file using POST data that it is handed. The following page definition works great for everything but IE8 (Internet Explorer 8):

```
<apex:page contentType="text/csv#{!fileName}.csv" 
        showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
     <apex:outputText value="{!input}" escape="false"/>
</apex:page>
```

with controller

```
public with sharing class ExportController {

// Controller for ExportData.page,
// which expects to be handed the following POST variables:
// @inputdata(string) data to export (i.e. in CSV format)
// @filename(string) name of the file to export, e.g. 'AccountData' 

public transient String input { public get; private set; }
public transient String fileName { public get; private set; }

public ExportController() {
    Map<String,String> params = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();

    // We expect to be handed POST variables called 'inputdata' and 'filename'
    fileName = params.get('filename');
    if (fileName == null) fileName = 'Data';

    input = params.get('inputdata');
    if (input == null) input = 'No data provided.';
}
}
```

In IE8, the error I get is:

> Internet Explorer cannot download ExportData from
>   nexus.na12.visual.force.com. Interent Explorer was not able to open
>   this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot
>   be found. Please try again later.

I know that the page is *not* unavailable, however, because I am getting debug logs from it using Developer Console. So it must be an IE8 file type handling issue of some sort.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to set `cache="true"` and `contentType="application/octet-stream`
 instead of `text/csv`.

```
<apex:page cache="true" 
        contentType="application/octet-stream#{!fileName}.csv" 
        showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
     <apex:outputText value="{!input}" escape="false"/>
</apex:page>
```

The key pieces here are `cache=true`, which, in conjunction with the default `expires=0` attribute, produces the following HTTP headers:

```
"Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
"Cache-Control: public"
```

And then the `contentType` of `application/octet-stream` --- which produces the following HTTP header:

```
"Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
```

See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232103/how-do-i-get-csv-file-to-download-on-ie-works-on-firefox/13093645#13093645) for additional explanation of IE8's handling of these headers.

Comment: IE... just can't resist making life hell for web developers. Do other browsers handle the content type correctly?

Comment: I've always had to do the cache and expires, but for csv I'd use text/csv for the content type

Comment: I had no problems with the `text/csv` content-type other than with IE8, and I didn't have to use cache and expires with other browsers either.

Answer (score -3):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" 
           extensions="unController" 
           contentType="application/azerty#personne.xml">

    <apex:outputText value="<personne>Toto</personne>" /> 

</apex:page>
```

**personne.xml** will  give the name of file.