# unable to save file from visualforce page in IE8

Tags: visualforce

I am unable to save csv file only in IE8. Can any one help me with this? I am getting an error that says "the site that you requested is either unavailable....". It is working fine in all other browsers and even in IE9. I have kept `cache="true"` also..

Here's what my Visualforce page looks like:

```
<apex:page controller="XXX" extensions="YYY" wizard="true" showHeader="false"
cache="true" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#{!accountName}docs">
```

Comment: Can you post some of the VF page code?  Especially the page tag?

Comment: Please check the page code Bellow:

Comment: <apex:page controller="XXX" extensions="YYY" wizard="true" showHeader="false" cache="true" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#{!accountName}docs">

Comment: Similar question here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/how-do-i-use-visualforce-to-generate-a-csv-file-that-can-be-downloaded-using-ie8

Comment: If the link posted by Peter above does not work for you, it could just be the settings in your IE8 browser(One of the worst for today's standards BTW).Try to uncheck the “Do not save encrypted pages to disk” option in the advanced internet options.

Answer (score 3):

Two things come to mind:

1. Try turning cache to False, at least to test if that has any root cause.
2. Try adding an extension to the filename, since it is IE we're talking about.  So `contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#{!accountName}docs.csv"` might be more effective.

Comment: I tried both the options. still the same behaviour. but this is only happening when i login to portal and progress through. it is working fine if i do it through developer mode. and when i login to portal my site pages will be on https and we have some authentication mechanism to acess the page